# Convertir a lista listas que están en formato str

Tags: python, pandas

estoy intentando recorrer una variable de un dataframe. Este dataframe tiene registros que son listas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo intento añadir cada uno de estos registros a una lista vacía, se me añaden como str y actúan como str.

```
prueba=[]

for i in df_fcbarcelona_def['suggestedWords']:
    prueba.append([i])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que quiero que funcionen en vez de str como list, para así poder recorrerlas e ir extrayendo cada una de las palabras que están dentro de estas listas.

He intentado realizar esto:

```
prueba=[]

for i in df_fcbarcelona_def['suggestedWords']:
    prueba.append(list(i))
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar, ya que me realiza lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si `my_str` es un string, es un iterable.
Por lo tanto `list(my_str)` será una lista de todos los elementos de `my_str`.
Es decir: una lista con todos los caracteres.
Así está recogido en la documentación de [`list`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Lo que tú quieres es interpretar una string como si fuera código de Python.
Lo que buscas exactamente está expuesto de varias formas en esta pregunta en inglés: [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990)

La forma más sencilla de lograr tu objetivo es evaluar la string como código de Python.
Para ello usamos la función: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).
Ten en cuenta que esta función ejecutará cualquier código de Python (siempre que defina un [literal](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)) que haya en tu dataframe, lo cual es una posible fuente de vulnerabilidades si cualquiera puede escribir en ese dataframe (sin embargo es mucho más seguro que [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#eval)).

En un entorno seguro bastará con escribir:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

prueba=[]
for i in df_fcbarcelona_def['suggestedWords']:
    prueba.append(literal_eval(i))
```

---

La otra opción que propone [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57373513) es evaluar la lista desde [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```py
prueba = pd.eval(df_fcbarcelona_def['suggestedWords'])
```